# efficiently reshaping 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

assuming I have a 2D numpy array and want to reshape it with strides into 3D, what would be the best way to do that?

little example:

```
def find_ngrams(input_list, n):
    return np.array(list(zip(*[input_list[i:] for i in range(n)])))

x = np.array(range(15))
x = x.reshape((5,3))
print(x)
print(x.shape)

res = find_ngrams(x, 3)
print(res.shape)
print(res)
```

This returns the expected result correctly:

```
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [12 13 14]]
(5, 3)
(3, 3, 3)
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]]

 [[ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]]]
```

However, how can I do this more efficiently, preferably using `stride_tricks`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it with `as_strided`:

```
window_length=3

strides = x.strides

new_len = (x.shape[0]-window_length+1)

out = as_strided(x,shape=(window_length, new_len, x.shape[1]),
                 strides=(strides[0],) + (strides[0], strides[1]))
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14]]])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it's not quite correct. If I input a (6,3) array, I get a (3, 4, 3) instead of a (4, 3, 3)